# PHP preg_replace not replacing the pattern

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I want to remove the single quote (') from start and end of the **to_date** function in query string.

```
$query = "'to_date('20-Jan-1970 4:00 AM','DD-MON-YYYY HH:MI AM')'";
```

The following pattern finds the string but does not replace it:

```
$query = preg_replace("/(['])(to_date[(].*[)])(['])/i", "${2}", $query);
```

The value of **$query** must change to:

```
to_date('20-Jan-1970 4:00 AM','DD-MON-YYYY HH:MI AM')
```

Current output:

```
Empty String ""
```

Comment: Remove the curly brackets in your replacement string. As an aside, you don't need to put single quotes in a character class, they aren't special characters, and you don't need to enclose them in a capture group for your task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it does, but you made a common mistake in using double-quoted string for replacement parameter. You have to remember that double-quoted strings cause string interpolation and where you have `${2}` there, PHP tries to look for a variable called `$2` before it even sends the parameter value to `preg_replace`. [Turning up error_reporting would reveal this upon inspecting your error logs](https://3v4l.org/vMs1S).

Simply replace `preg_replace("/(['])(to_date[(].*[)])(['])/i", "${2}", $query);` with `preg_replace("/(['])(to_date[(].*[)])(['])/i", '$2', $query);` and all is well or you could just opt to use the more favorable `\\2` for replacement which is what I go for.

**Also note you really don't even need a regex for this technically.** You could use `substr($query, 1, -1);` all the same.

Comment: substr cannot be used in this case because the STRING in question is actually part of a larger DB query string.

Answer (score -2):

```
$query=substr(substr($query,1),0,-1);
```